# How to conditionally call fields in a table in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce

I'm wanting to show on the visualforce page a table with the value of fields that I take from a list. However, some fields should only appear conditionally:
VisualForcePage:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Estudante}" var="item" rendered="true"> 
              <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Estudante:</td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!item.Name}</td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!item.Matric__c}</td>
                        </tr>
                                                     
                      <apex:outputText rendered="{!proc}">
                           <tr> <td>{!item.aluno.Lista_de_Freq__r.Faltas}</td></tr>
                        </apex:outputText>    
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Outside of "<apex:outputText " these fields appear normally, but I need them to appear conditionally... does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The issue could just be a result of the syntax you have for the `if` statement. It should be `{! IF(conditionTest, true, false) }`. If `item.proc` is a boolean, you should be able to simply write `rendered="{! item.proc }"`.

Comment: Thank you! Please put your comment as an answer so I can Mark it as The solution :) @MarkPond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could just be a result of the syntax you have for the if statement.

It should be `{! IF(conditionTest, true, false) }`.

If `item.proc` is a boolean, you should be able to simply write `rendered="{! item.proc }"`